# How to return const reference of a vector?

Tags: c++

I have the following setup:

***A.h***

```
class A
{
public:
    ...
    const std::vector<int>& getSomeData() const;

private:
    std::map<SomeIdType, std::shared_ptr<SomeDataType> > m_someDataCollection;
}
```

***A.cpp***

```
const std::vector<int>& getSomeData(SomeIdType id) const
{
    std::vector<int> rVal;

    auto it = m_someDataCollection.find(id);
    if (it != m_someDataCollection.end())
    {
        std::shared_ptr<SomeDataType> someData = it->second;
        rVal = someData->getSomeDataVector(); // returns std::vector<int>
    }
    return  rVal;
}
```

```
int main()
{
    SomeIdType id;
    A a;
    ...
    const std::vector<int>& data = a.getSomeData(id);
}
```

There is a reference to a local variable returned in *A.cpp*.

I don't want the vector returned by `A::getSomeData()` to be manipulated outside.

How can I achieve this goal, without having to return a reference to a local variable in *A.cpp*?

Comment: Use `std::vector<int> getSomeData(SomeIdType id) const`. whereas user can still modify returned vector, that doesn't affect the current class instance.

Comment: If the id is not found in m_someDataCollection, it should return a reference to an empty vector, right?

Comment: @Jarod42 that will copy the entire vector (usually).

Comment: @user253751: *"`someData->getSomeDataVector(); // returns std::vector<int>`"* that already does copy.

Comment: Either return non-reference or change `std::vector<int> rVal;` to `const std::vector<int> &rVal;` but then you need to figure out what to do when the if condition is not fulfilled. Maybe return some kind of optional or just a pointer?

Comment: @user253751 The vector will be moved  (`return id-expression;` naming a local variable is a move context, and a copy elision context)

Comment: @Jarod42 right.

Comment: It would help to show the declaration of `getSomeDataVector` , it is important to the answers whether this returns by value or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that when the id is found in the data, you want to return a reference to that id's vector instead of copying the entire vector.

For the empty case, you could return a reference to a `static` local variable which is always empty:

```
const std::vector<int>& getSomeData(SomeIdType id) const
{
    auto it = m_someDataCollection.find(id);
    if (it != m_someDataCollection.end())
    {
        return it->second->getSomeDataVector(); // returns const std::vector<int>&
    }
    else
    {
        static const std::vector<int> emptyVector;
        return emptyVector;
    }
}
```

Comment: The question specified `getSomeDataVector()` as returning by value,  so this will return a dangling reference

Answer (score 4):

> How to return const reference of a vector?

1. By creating the vector somewhere other than the function. Since it is a member function in this case, an option is to return reference to a member. Or the vector could be passed into the function through a parameter.
2. Or by using a static local variable. In that case all invcations of the function would return the same vector.

Any non-static local variable don't want the vector returned by A::getSomeData() to be manipulated outside.e has automatic storage and therefore exists only until the function ends. A returned reference to such variable will be referring to a destroyed vector.

---

That said, it looks like from your example that you should probably return the vector by value instead of trying to return a reference.

> I don't want the vector returned by A::getSomeData() to be manipulated outside.

You haven't given a reason for why you would want that. Why should you care what the caller does with the vector that you've returned?

Answer (score 3):

After you convert the values to `int`, they no longer refer to the original data, so it cannot be modified by the caller. It is safe to return the vector by value. If the vector were to contain pointers or references, it would not be safe.

```
std::vector<int> getSomeData(SomeIdType id) const
{
    auto it = m_someDataCollection.find(id);
    if (it != m_someDataCollection.end())
    {
        std::shared_ptr<SomeDataType> someData = it->second;
        return someData->getSomeDataVector(); // returns std::vector<int>
    }
    return {};
}

const auto data = a.getSomeData(id);
```

Comment: @eerorika the return statement is a move context anyway so it's negligible overhead

Comment: now, `return std::move(rVal);` is definitely a bad idea

Comment: @M.M What is negligible overhead depends on context. Without context, you can only guess.

Comment: OP wants to return const reference but you are returning a copy

Comment: @NutCracker OP request is impractical so the answers are suggesting other ways to solve the problem OP is facing

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C++17, one of the possibilities would also be to use [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional). In case you have found an element with the specified ID, you would return `std::vector`. Otherwise, you would return [`std::nullopt`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/nullopt). Here is how your code would in this case look like:

```cpp
std::optional<std::vector<int>> getSomeData(SomeIdType id) const {
    auto it = m_someDataCollection.find(id);
    if (it != m_someDataCollection.end()) {
        return it->second->getSomeDataVector();
    }
    else {
        return {}; // or return std::nullopt;
    }
}
```

And then you could use it like this:

```cpp
int main() {
    SomeIdType id;
    A a;

    // ...

    auto data = a.getSomeData(id);
    if (data) {
        // there is an item with the specified ID
        // example of accessing the std::vector
        for (auto const i : data.value().get()) {
            // more code here ....
        }
    } else {
        // there is NO item with the specified ID
    }
}
```

Comment: `getSomeDataVector()` returns by value (according to code comments in the question -- the actual code was not shown) , so this will return a dangling reference_wrapper

Comment: @M.M did the OP really stated that? Haven't seen it. Sorry. It is fixed now. Thanks